# SQL Server and EF Core, create "Lock Request Timeout" error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I recently had my EF Core (2.1) code throw a `DbUpdateException`, caused by a lock request timeout. I *think* I understand the basic idea behind this (EF doesn't lock items until it tries to update, via `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync()` - which is where the exception stack trace came through).

What I want to do is **force** the error condition, to verify that my handling of the exception is working correctly. I tried creating an open transaction on the same record in SSMS, but that gave me the general command timeout rather than the lock request timeout.

Any ideas on how to force this error for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Run SQL to update a table and not commit the transaction

```
begin transaction t1


SELECT TOP (1) 1 
FROM dbo.Table WITH (TABLOCKX)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:59:00'
```

Step 2: Do stuff in EF that uses dbo.Table you left with an open transaction

Step 3: Reproduce error

When done, you can run `rollback transaction t1`

Comment: I believe I had tried that - but instead of the "lock request timeout", I'm getting a "command timeout" instead.

Comment: I revised the answer @BillTurner

Comment: We were both on the right track - but I missed that running the code was running in an Azure function, and that it implicitly sets LOCK_TIMEOUT. Without setting LOCK_TIMEOUT, I'd get a command timeout instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by default LOCK_TIMEOUT is -1 (doesn't timeout the lock), so command timeout gets hit instead. The code I was trying to test was running in an Azure function, which apparently sets LOCK_TIMEOUT.

If I set LOCK_TIMEOUT, I do get the lock request timeout rather than the command timeout.